# How to center glossary group headings

Tags: glossaries

I'm using the glossaries package with listgroup style. I just need the glossary group headings (A, B .. ) centered. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome! Rather hard to help without an example. Not, perhaps, impossible, but certainly much more difficult. Please make a small example document (minimal example) which we can compile to reproduce your situation and (hopefully) use to illustrate possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You would be far better advised to pick a different style if you want centred headings. This will almost certainly not work correctly.

[image: centred]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=listgroup]{glossaries}
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{\item[]\makebox[\linewidth]{\glsgetgrouptitle{#1}}}
\makeglossary
\newglossaryentry{aa}{%
  name = aa,
  description = {AA aa}}
\newglossaryentry{bb}{%
  name = bb,
  description = {BB bb}}
\begin{document}
  \gls{aa} \gls{bb}
  \printglossary
\end{document}
```